# Button Release Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

Here's my situation. I have two tkinter buttons:

1. Play Button: plays a sound
2. Stop Button: to stop the sound during play

Code is as follows:

```
def Play(self):
    //plays a file with pygame module

def Stop(self):
    //Stop using pygame stop


Button( root, text ='Play', command= Play).pack()
Button( root, text ='Stop', command= Stop).pack()
```

The issue is that, when I click the 'Play' button, it stays pressed until it completes playing the sound, freezing the entire program, not allowing me to press 'stop' button during that time.

How do i prevent the program from freezing while the play is in progress to allow me to do other things like stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to prevent the GUI from freezing while the song is playing is to use a separate thread or separate processes to play the song. As long as the function that plays the song is running and in the main thread, the event loop can't run. If the event loop can't run, the GUI will be frozen.

Comment: threading is too complex for me right now, i need to read a lot for that. Meanwhile, i inserted root.update() and it works for me. i have read your comments where you say this is dangerous but given my current knowledge and how discussions of threading sound like greek, i think i will go with root.update().. thanks for replying :)

Comment: trying to implement threading as suggested by you.  request you to please look at my code structure at http://codepad.org/dau5UA1O.. i am having tough time organizing the code. Suggestions would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This tip was [proposed here](http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-tkinter-discuss/2798/)

Instead of:

```
Button(tkwin, text="Go", command=dosomething)
```

Put instead:

```
def delayedDoSomething():
       tkwin.after(100, dosomething)

Button(tkwin, text="Go", command=delayedDoSomething)
```

You may try, for your code, to write a `customPlay` method that run what you wanted to run with Play in a second thread. At least, you can get inspiration from this method-rewriting tip.

Maybe you can use [mtTkinter, a thread safe version of Tkinter](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/mtTkinter).

> Although Tkinter is technically thread-safe (assuming Tk is built with
>   --enable-threads), practically speaking there are still problems when used in multithreaded Python applications. The problems stem from the
>   fact that the _tkinter module attempts to gain control of the main
>   thread via a polling technique when processing calls from other
>   threads. If it succeeds, all is well. If it fails (i.e., after a
>   timeout), the application receives an exception with the message:
>   "RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop". There is no way to
>   tell when this might happen, so calling Tk routines from multiple
>   threads seems to be problematic at best.

Comment: this does not work for me :(. Just a query, here tkwin refers to parent frame - right ?  i also tried the advance version mentioned [there]http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-tkinter-discuss/2798/  but the code seems to have a reference to a method  self.updateDisplay() which is defined nowhere. Any ideas ?

Comment: is not a line of code to be copy pasted as is. i am just hinting at some possible work around, defining YOUR OWN Play method

Comment: hey i am not copying exact thing..I am sure applying the concept to mymethods. I even tried increasing the time from 100 to 1000 or 10000 - does not retract the button.

Comment: Delaying what happens when the button is pressed won't solve the problem. The root of the issue is that tkinter is single threaded, so while the song is playing the GUI will be unresponsive. The only choice is to play the song in another thread or another process.